# Where's Codsworth?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing Fallout 4 on PC, on survival difficulty. I have all of the DLCs. I don't play with mods except for a few free 'Creation Club' items.

I took Codsworth with me to clear out USAF Satellite Station Olivia and retrieve the locket. The raiders were too strong, however -- they knocked out Codsworth. Since I have 'Automatron', I needed a robot repair kit to heal him rather than a stimpack, but I didn't have one.

Soon, there was a message that said that Codsworth was returning to Sanctuary Hills. I had to retreat anyway because I couldn't take on the raider boss on my own, so I made my way back to Sanctuary Hills as well.

However, Codsworth isn't in Sanctuary Hills. I picked up Dogmeat, and we went back to Station Olivia and cleared out the remaining raiders. Codsworth wasn't there either. I took two different routes between Sanctuary and Olivia -- following the road South of Thicket Excavations through Concord, and also through the wilderness north of Thicket Excavations -- and didn't see him on either of those paths.

As a last resort, I built the 'Vault-Tec Population Management System' in Sanctuary and powered it up. But the only "VIP" it identified on the companion tracker was Dogmeat (the only companion I've unlocked besides Codsworth so far.)

Where is Codsworth? How do I find him? If I wait long enough, will he eventually show up in Sanctuary? Keeping in mind that I have no console (since this is Survival mode), is there some way to find him faster ... since I'd rather travel with him than Dogmeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The *Vault-Tec Population Management System* [cannot track Codsworth](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Overseer%27s_Most_Wanted#Notes), so that wouldn't have helped you anyway.
- No real [bugs](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Codsworth#Bugs) that involve Codsworth getting lost seem to exist. The only one that might be interesting is:

  > Codsworth may sometimes stay in one place when dismissed to a settlement (even if outside the building boundary), and rarely move around or perform tasks except to fight hostile enemies.

  But since you already revisited Station Olivia, this probably doesn't apply to your situation.
- What I can suggest is that, assuming the buildable bounds of settlements are the same as those for dismissed companions, to keep looking around Sanctuary, as there is quite a lot of ground to cover:

  [image: collage of PipBoy screenshots of the map of Sanctuary]
  <sup>source: [Reddit user IGG_Jan](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3tfav2/sanctuary_hills_map_for_planning_base_building/)</sup>

  **Check behind and inside the houses, [in the river](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s8ffw/comment/cyjwmkd), and [on the roofs](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s8ffw/comment/cxf0543).**

  In case you're thinking of just ringing [the settlement bell](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Bell#Notes):

  > Companions, including inactive potential **companions, ignore the sound of the bell**.
- In case you're on PC, you can also use console commands:

  - `prid 0001ca7d` to select Codsworth;
  - `moveto player` to teleport Codsworth to you.

  To enable the console commands while in Survival mode, you can either use a mod like [this one](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/12794/?), or follow the following steps (command from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/5rb40b/psa_console_command_to_reactivate_survival_mode/), additional steps from [here](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/4061865-survival-mode-console-enabler/page-11#entry60014366)):

  > 1. Disable survival mode;
  > 2. Run all the console commands you need;
  > 3. Run a command that will allow you to re-enable survival mode: 
  >    `cgf "Game.IncrementStat" "Survival Denied" -1`;
  > 4. Go to settings and re-enable Survival mode

Comment: Assuming that Codsworth *has* returned to Sanctuary, but OP just can't spot him, would building and ringing a Bell to gather everyone together help?

Comment: +1 but Roddy can't use console commands when playing Survival mode

Comment: @Chronocidal It won't work for companions — I updated my answer.

Comment: @Robotnik You can circumvent that — I updated my answer.

Comment: As an aside, the unofficial fallout 4 patch mod fixes the 'cannot track Codsworth' bug with the Vault-Tec Population Management System.